# Use of .sync in step function for ECS Tasks

Tags: amazon-web-services, amazon-ecs, aws-step-functions

How does the step function know when the ECS Task has finished executing an API, when using .sync? Any help will be appreciated

Comment: https://docs.aws.amazon.com/step-functions/latest/dg/connect-to-resource.html

Answer (score 2):

> How does the step function know when the ECS Task has finished
> executing an API, when using .sync?

It just waits for the task to exit. There is no way for Step Functions to know if the task succeeded or failed when using `.sync` it just knows the task finished running.

If you want Step Functions to wait for ECS to send back a success response, you need to use `.waitForTaskToken` instead.

Comment: Alright. but how do we call any endpoint hosted on ecs? It looks like there is only a run task step and no way to pass any api there?

Comment: Calling an endpoint of some application you happen to be hosting on ECS is completely unrelated to the Step Functions ECS integration. To call an endpoint, it doesn't matter if it is hosted on ECS or EKS or EC2 or a computer running entirely outside of AWS, you would write a Lambda function to make whatever the appropriate API calls are against whatever API you have created, and then have Step Functions call that Lambda function.